# Is there a way to tell ReSharper what type of values it should suggest, specifically in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resharper

If I place the caret between the quotes of the `Value` property of:

```
<Trigger Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="|"></Trigger>
```

and ask `ReSharper` to autocomplete - it identifies the type according to the `Property` property (`enum System.Windows.Visibility`) and suggests the right values (`Collaspsed`, `Hidden` and `Visible`).

However when I create these two dependency properties in my own object (a `Behavior<UIElement>` specifically), `ReSharper` obviously remains indifferent when I ask it to autocomplete the `Value` property (since it's unable to know about the relation to `Property` type):

```
<vc:SetPropertyBehavior Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="|"/>
```

So my question is whether this information (regarding `Trigger.Property` and `Trigger.Value` types in this examples) is built-into `ReSharper` and cannot be changed, or is there a way to tell `ReSharper` about the type of a certain `XAML` dependency-property (some attribute on the parameters maybe?)?